# How do you kill a Jerk with the Spiked Shield?

Tags: achievements, grindstone

The *Spiked!* challenge in Grindstone says to *Kill a Jerk with the Spiked Shield*. Defending with the Spiked Shield does 1 damage to an attacking enemy, but you can only use the Spiked Shield 3 times per fight. A regular Jerk has 10hp.

How do you kill a Jerk with the Spiked Shield?

[image: Spiked challenge description]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Equip damaging items in your 2 other equipment slots to weaken the Jerk, then finish it off by blocking with the Spiked Shield.

Stage 12 is a good place to get this. It's an early level that starts with two Jerks on the board. To weaken the enemy, I recommend using the Vine Sword, Poison Arrow, or Poison Shield. I personally accomplished this with the Vine Sword.

[image: 10hp jerk being attacked with vine sword]

[image: 5hp jerk attacked with the vine sword]

[image: Spiked shield block at 1hp]

[image: Dead jerk, spiked achievement]